# AWS Elastic beanstalk RDS connection error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

we are trying to connect to an RDS mysql database from an Elastic beanstalk application. it is giving an error regarding SSL certificate. am unable to understand what could be the exact reason.

currently the application is a test/dev application and used default Amazon domain . the screenshot of the error is as under:

[image: Mysql rds ssl error]

any help appreciated.

EDIT:
we are able to connect to RDS fine with any RDBMS client (e.g. workbench), local code and even application deployed on another server.

Comment: Here are the steps mentioned to solve  this common issue error:https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ssl-connection/

Comment: @prashantthakre Thank you for the comment. Can you also guide that do we need to give these parameter in the application connection string (because we are getting this error when trying to connect from beanstalk application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by setting SSL mode to None in MySQL connection string :).
as per personal understanding, the likely reason is that .Net 5.0 uses TLS 1.3 and Linux version of Amazon Beanstalk does not seem to support it (at least thats how I understand that). So at the moment disabling SSL for MySQL did the trick.